# AWS SQS Listener - Circuit Breaker

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have built a SQS Listener that polls messages off SQS and sends the messages over to a REST service. If the REST service is down , I don't want to pull messages off the queue until it is ready. I am using spring cloud to read messages off SQS. Are there any examples of how this can be achieved?

I have configured Dead Letter Queue for this queue. I don't want all the messages to end up in DLQ if the backend service is down.

```
@Configuration
public class SqsListenerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "aws.configuration")
    public ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration() {
        return new ClientConfiguration();
    }


    @Bean
    @Primary
    public AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider() {

        ProfileCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new ProfileCredentialsProvider("credential");
        try {
            credentialsProvider.getCredentials();
            System.out.println(credentialsProvider.getCredentials().getAWSAccessKeyId());
            System.out.println(credentialsProvider.getCredentials().getAWSSecretKey());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AmazonClientException(
                    "Cannot load the credentials from the credential profiles file. " +
                            "Please make sure that your credentials file is at the correct " +
                            "location (~/.aws/credentials), and is in valid format.",
                    e);
        }
        return credentialsProvider;
    }


    @Bean
    @Primary
    public AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync() {
        return AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder.standard().
                withCredentials(awsCredentialsProvider()).
                withClientConfiguration(clientConfiguration()).
                build();
    }


    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "aws.queue")
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer(AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setAmazonSqs(amazonSQSAsync);
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setMessageHandler(queueMessageHandler());
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setMaxNumberOfMessages(10);
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setTaskExecutor(threadPoolTaskExecutor());
        return simpleMessageListenerContainer;
    }


    @Bean
    public QueueMessageHandler queueMessageHandler() {
        QueueMessageHandlerFactory queueMessageHandlerFactory = new QueueMessageHandlerFactory();
        queueMessageHandlerFactory.setAmazonSqs(amazonSQSAsync());
        QueueMessageHandler queueMessageHandler = queueMessageHandlerFactory.createQueueMessageHandler();
        return queueMessageHandler;
    }


    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(1);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(1);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("oaoQueueExecutor");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }


    @Bean
    public QueueMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate(@Autowired AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync) {
        return new QueueMessagingTemplate(amazonSQSAsync);
    }


}
```

**Listener**

```
    @SqsListener(value = "${oao.sqs.url}", deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS)
    public void onMessage(String serviceData, @Header("MessageId") String messageId, @Header("ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp") String approximateFirstReceiveTimestamp) {

        System.out.println(" Data = " + serviceData + " MessageId = " + messageId);

        repository.execute(serviceData);
}
```

Comment: I believe the contract for your `onMessage` method is if it throws an Exception the message will not be deleted. Or do you mean you just don't want `onMethod` to execute until the REST is ready?

Comment: Yes , that's correct. It becomes available after visibility timeout. Yes - I would like to stop polling queue for messages when I know that I cannot process the message due to one of systems that I depend on is unavailable.

Comment: Have you considered doing this without Spring?  Normally you just have a loop polling SQS and, for each message, you have to decide to delete it.  If the other service is down then just don't delete it and stop polling for some amount of time.  I'd guess that it's the same or less code than you show above.

Comment: Thanks @stdunbar. Yes , I would like to use Spring libraries for this. However I am unable to figure out a way to use any spring config that may be available to control polling,